# Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php using 'use_include_path' = true

Tags: zend-framework

Im getting the above mentiond error. The Problem is that the file "Loader.php" doesnt exit in the the zend framework that I downloaded (ZendFramework-2.3.2). please assist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such file in Zend Framework 2. It sounds like you're following an out of date tutorial which was written for an early version of ZF1.